# Caliburn.micro propertychanged problem in a view

Tags: inotifypropertychanged, caliburn

I use Caliburn.Micro for my Silverlight application.
I have a view/viewmodel to create a new Item.
On the view there is one combobox.
The first time I open the view , fill in all fields, the Item is saved correctly.
The second time I open the view, fill in all fields, all teh values of them are changed in the object, except the value of the combobox, this property of Item stays 0 (it's an integer).

Any ideas why this is? I think the Caliburn framework is doing something weird.

thanks,

Filip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to open the view was:
EventAggreg.EventAgg.Publish(new ObjectDetailEvent() { ObjectDetail = new ObjectDTO() });

I replaced it with:
EventAggreg.EventAgg.Publish(new ObjectDetailEvent() { ObjectDetail = new ObjectDTO { LandId = 0 } });

LandId is the property bound to the combobox.
So when this is filled in by default, teh notify works perfect every time.